# Unable to fetch the images and content for an e-commerce product at a time from firebase database using react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I wanna upload data into firebase database for an e-commerce site.
I'm  done uploading the content like (product name, details, price etc.) into firebase collection, and respective image into firebase storage.
But, I'm unable to fetch the images and content simultaneously and display.
Help me out guys...

```
const [offer, setOffer] = useState([]);
  

  const getOffers = async () => {
    const dataRef = collection(db, "offers");
    const q = query(dataRef, orderBy("id"));
    await getDocs(q)
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const newData = querySnapshot.docs.map((item) => ({
          ...item.data(),
          id: item.data().id,
          name: item.data().name,
          description: item.data().description,
        }));
        setOffer(newData);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

according to my understanding, you have defined a function getOffers but didn't call it in this code if you have called this function inside your useEffect or useLayoutEffect function it should work though the code you provided seems incorrect if you can share more of the same component I might be able to point out why the data is not being set